# Matlab code is a lot faster than C# code not expected

Tags: c#, matlab, optimization, runtime

```
int n = varRatio.Count * varRatio[0].Count;
        double[] y_0 = new double[var_ratio_ne.Count];
        double[] y_n = new double[y_0.Length];
        double[] var_map = new double[y_0.Length];
        double[] var_fa_map = new double[y_0.Length];
        for (int j = 0; j < var_width.Count; j++)
        {
            List<double> tempRow = new List<double>();
            for (int index = 0; index < var_ratio_ne.Count; index++)
            {
                y_0[index] = ( (var_ratio_ne[index] - var_thr[0]) / var_width[j]);
            }
            double inc = delta / var_width[j];
            for (int i = 0; i < var_thr.Count; i++)
            {
                if (var_thr[i] >= curr_max)
                {
                    break;
                }
                Parallel.For(0, y_0.Length, k =>
                {
                    y_n[k] = y_0[k] - i*inc;
                    var_map[k] = Math.Min(Math.Max(y_n[k], 0), 1);
                    var_fa_map[k] = (not_edge_map[k]*var_map[k]);
                });
                tempRow.Add(var_fa_map.Sum() / n);
            }
            var_measure.Add(tempRow);
        }
```

Here is the matlab code I'm converting:

```
curr_max = max(var_ratio(:));
N = numel(var_ratio);
for j = 1:numel(var_width)
    y_0 = (var_ratio_ne - var_thr(1))/var_width(j);
    inc = delta/var_width(j);
    z = not_edge_map;
    for i = 1:numel(var_thr)
        if var_thr(i)>=curr_max
            break;
        end
        y_n = y_0 - (i-1)*inc;
        var_map = min(max(y_n,0),1);
        var_fa_map = z.*var_map;
        var_measure(i,j) = sum(var_fa_map(:))/N;
        % optimization for matlab: pixels that didn't contribute to the false alarm in this
        % iteration will not contribute in the next one as well becouse the treshold increses so we can throw them out 
        ii = y_n>0;
        y_0 = y_0(ii);
        z = z(ii);
    end
end
```

The sizes of the arrays are:

- N = 673326
- var_ratio_ne = 586417
- var_thr = 131072
- var_width = [15 30 45]
- not_edge_map = 586417
- var_ratio = 666x1011 double matrix

UPDATE: my code runs a lot faster after this change

```
    //N = numel(var_ratio);
    int n = varRatio.Count * varRatio[0].Count;
    double[] y_0 = new double[var_ratio_ne.Count];
    for (int j = 0; j < var_width.Count; j++)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < var_ratio_ne.Count; index++)
        {
            y_0[index] = ( (var_ratio_ne[index] - var_thr[0]) / var_width[j]);
        }
        double inc = delta / var_width[j];
        int indexOF = var_thr.FindIndex(x => x >= curr_max);
        double[] tempRow = new double[indexOF];
        Parallel.For(0, indexOF ,i =>
        {
            var total = 0d;
            for (int k = 0; k < y_0.Length; k++)
            {
                total += (not_edge_map[k] * Math.Min(Math.Max(y_0[k] - i * inc, 0), 1));
            }
            tempRow[i] = total/n;
        });

        List<double> tempRowList = new List<double>();
        //copy the results of Parallel compute
        for (int i = 0; i < indexOF; i++)
        {
            tempRowList.Add(tempRow[i]);
        }
        //fill the rest with zeros
        for (int i = indexOF; i < var_thr.Count; i++)
        {
            tempRowList.Add(0);
        }
        var_measure.Add(tempRowList);
    }
```

I think I'm over calculating something here. Although I'm running in Debug mode, the performance of C#(in minutes) is terrible compared to matlab(~20 seconds).
Can you please help me with the runtime optimization? I find it hard to understand why matlab performs better than the C# code.

Comment: C# will be faster as a general purpose language, but MATLAB is designed to calculate mathematical expressions. So when all your program is doing is crunching a bunch of numbers, MATLAB will win every time.

Comment: If you include all of the code then we may be able to optimize certain parts, but in it's current form there isn't enough info to get it to compile without assuming an awful lot.

Comment: @Abion47 my post is about this specific piece of code, there are many examples where matlab has the upper hand, and many examples for C# having the upper hand. I need help with this specific piece of code, and why is this so slow comparing to the matlab code.

Comment: @Stuart this is all of the code, the rest is just init the matrices to their data. what else are you missing please say and I will complete the code.

Comment: The declarations of those variables, i.e. what are their types, and what the data is, cause the sizes will influence the optimizations.

Comment: Everything is double[]

Comment: So what is varRatio?

Comment: @Stuart var_ratio = 666x1011 double matrix, also update the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132035/discussion-between-stuart-and-gilad).

Comment: How fast is the c# in release mode?

Comment: @Peheje about 10 mins, not very different from Debug. maybe it will be helpful to use TPL a little bit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest reducing large allocations, so this:

```
List<double> y_n = new List<double>();
List<double> var_map = new List<double>();
List<double> var_fa_map = new List<double>();
for (int k = 0; k < y_0.Count; k++)
{
    y_n.Add(y_0[k] - i * inc);
    var_map.Add(Math.Min(Math.Max(y_n[k], 0), 1));
    var_fa_map.Add(not_edge_map[k] * var_map[k]);
}
tempRow.Add(var_fa_map.Sum() / n);
```

becomes:

```
var total = 0d;
for (int k = 0; k < y_0.Count; k++)
{
    total += (not_edge_map[k] * Math.Min(Math.Max(y_0[k] - i * inc, 0), 1));
}       
tempRow.Add(total / n);
```

In my tests this halves the time, but your milage may vary. There are other optimizations to be made for sure like reducing allocations and combining some of the computational tasks, but I'd need better representative inputs to be able to profile it effectively, for example I'm not sure if making this parallel and switching to concurrent collections will have a positive effect.

Comment: thanks I did it, it doesn't effect performance a lot on my end.

Comment: a little faster, I will profile tomorrow, to see the exact difference. but something here is very weird to me, the amount of time it take to iterate over the matrices is too big.  thanks anyway  i gave +1